# How to get a simple CSS 3D flip working on IE 10 and IOS Safari 8.1?

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple flip card containing two sides.

On hover, it rotates 180 degrees along the y axis to make the other side visible.

It works as intended on chrome but on IE 10 and 11, it shows the mirrored front side instead of the back side of the card. From looking at [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform), I think the issue is in the `transform-style: preserve -3d` css property.

Is there anyway of getting this working on IE and possibly IOS safari 8.1?

Please check out below fiddle and try it on IE and Chrome to see the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/vbknwjhq/5/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">    
   <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
             <p > front </p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">               
             <p>   back</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran into this same problem for a about page I created earlier in the year. I ended up ditching the whole idea as I could not find a work around for 3D transforms on those browsers.

Comment: Just been looking at this page as it actually works on IE 11. Let me know if you figure out how it works. Thanks. http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: It was a commercial project so had to support at least ie9. I just don't think 3D flips are ready for production for another year or so.

Answer (score 4):

This one works on latest version of browser Chrome,Firefox,IE,Opera and Safari.

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/sx3fqe7b/

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="cardFront">Front</div>
        <div class="cardBack">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$('.card').hover(function(){$('.card').toggleClass('applyflip');}.bind(this));
```

---

```
  .card {
        perspective: 1000px;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
        -moz-perspective: 1000px;
        -o-perspective: 1000px;
        -ms-perspective: 1000px;
        margin:80px 150px;
        width:100px;
        height:200px;
        vertical-align:top;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        font-size:25px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .card .content {
        transition: 0.5s ease-out;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

        /* content backface is visible so that static content still appears */
        backface-visibility: visible;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
        -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
        -o-backface-visibility: visible;
        -ms-backface-visibility: visible;


        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 15px;
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }
    .card.applyflip .content {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }



    .card .content .cardFront {
        background-color: skyblue;
        color: yellow;
    }

    .card .content .cardBack {
        background-color: tomato;
        color: skyblue;
    }

    .card .content .cardFront, .card .content .cardBack {
        /* Backface visibility works great for all but IE. As such, we mark the backface visible in IE and manage visibility ourselves */
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        line-height:200px;
        border-radius: 14px;
    }
    .card .content .cardFront, .card.applyflip .content .cardFront {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    .card .content .cardBack, .card.applyflip .content .cardBack {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }

    .card .content .cardFront, .card.applyflip .content .cardBack {
        /* IE Hack. Halfway through the card flip, set visibility. Keep other browsers visible throughout the card flip. */
        animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -webkit-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -moz-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -o-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -ms-animation: donothing 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.17s;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .card.applyflip .content .cardFront, .card .content .cardBack {
        /* IE Hack. Halfway through the card flip, set visibility. Keep other browsers visible throughout the card flip. */
        animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -webkit-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -moz-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -o-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
        -ms-animation: donothing 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.17s;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    @keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }
    @-webkit-keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }
    @-moz-keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }
    @-o-keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }

@-ms-keyframes donothing { 0% { } 100% { } }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this as a second option as I'm looking for a solution using pure html and css.